# Still Remain there when Resize the windows screen

Tags: jquery

hihi guys, the problem is when i resize the screen below 768px, the function is works, everything is fine, but when i drag and resize the window screen **more than 768px**, the ** height(); function is still remain on there** , but if i **refresh the page, the height(); function just will be disappear**.
may i know where is the problem?

```
modalPop : function() {
(function($) {
    //
    'use strict';

    // modal
    var popups = $('.modal-boz'),
        totalPopups = popups.length;

    if ( popups.length ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < totalPopups; i++ ) {
            var popup = $(popups[i]);

            popup.each(function() {

                $(this).children('a.cta').click(function(e) {
                    $(this).parent().children('.popup-modal').fadeIn(350);
                    if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
                        var _topPos = $('body').height() - $('.popup-modal .form-wrapper').height();
                        _topPos-= 300;
                        $('.popup-modal > .modal-content').css('top',_topPos+'px');
                    } else {
                        // 
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

}

Comment: If your ui just depend on screensize, why not use css media query to styling?

Comment: create a jsfiddle example or any other sandbox to see in working example all you mean. There's completely misunderstanding why you use $(this) here and whether you use it correctly. So.. give a working example!